# Given two unsorted arrays find the number of pairs where A[i] > X and B[i] > Y

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We are given two unsorted arrays. We have to find the number of pairs such that for each pair A[i] > X and B[i] > Y. We will have to process 1 million such queries where each query will have different X and Y given. The length of the array will also be up to 1 million.

Constraints :

1 <=A[i],B[i],X,Y <=10^9
1<= A.size, B.size, Number of Queries <= 10^6

For ex :

```
     A = [7,2,10,15,12,9]
     B = [10,8,5,3,4,7]
```

Queries :

```
      X Y   o/p
      9 3    2  (As we have 2 pairs which satisfy above condition (10,5), (12,4))
      6 4    3  (As we have 3 pairs which satisfy above condition (7,10), (10,5), (9,7))
```

Is there any better approach than brute force as we have 1 million such queries?

Comment: Finding all values in an unsorted array that match a certain condition can't be done in better than linear time. Usually the best approach in speeding this up is to trade-off space for time by changing the data structure or introducing a new one to be more lookup-optimized

Comment: Input Array range?

Comment: What is the size of X, Y and the contents of A, B? If they are relatively small you can efficiently precompute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the queries are provided offline, there's no need for a quad tree and we can solve this in `O(n log n)`. Insert all query-pairs and array-pairs into one list, sorted by `X` or `a` (if an `X` is equal to an `a`, place the query pair after the array pair). Process the pairs in the list by descending order (of `a` or `X`). If it's an array pair, insert it into an order-statistic tree ordered by `b`. If it's a query, look up in the tree the count of tree nodes (these are array pairs) that have `b > Y` (we already know all pairs in the tree have `a > X`).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on order-statistc tree?

Comment: @Bhargavkular please see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

Answer (score 1):

A [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) would be better than brute force. Interpret the pairs (a, b) as 2D co-ordinates of points, and insert them into a quadtree. Each node in the quadtree should also store its cardinality, i.e. the number of points within the area represented by that node. Each point-counting query can then be answered recursively on the quadtree, where the base case is a node whose area is either completely contained within the region `a > X && b > Y` (in which case return the node's cardinality), or completely disjoint from it (in which case return 0).

Other similar data structures such as a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) could be used similarly.